# SQL EXPRESS Cant save changes to table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I have a big problem. I want to change something in my table from char to nchar (same size) and I'm getting this error:

[image: SQL error]
Anyone know what to do about that?

Comment: Looks like you lost connection to the database. Try again after re-connecting.

Comment: I tried reconnecting a lot of times, even detach and attach, restarting, ... nothing helped

Answer (score 0):

Have you deselect the *"Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation"* under

> `Tools->Options->Designers`

in MSSMS?

Comment: Could be this but you usually get a decent error message rather than a dropped connection... weird!

Comment: Unfortunately I have that deselected.